# How to convert syslog timestamp to epoch number in logstash

Tags: java, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have logs that log the time in syslog format. I want to make a metadata tag of that timestamp converted to the epoch time to use for output to graphite.

This is what I have so far. I don't believe that the date filter does what I was hoping it would do, which is to take a timestamp and convert it. Is there a way to filter a syslog timestamp and mutate it to an epoch number?

```
filter {
  if [type] == "uwsgi-syslog" {
    grok { match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }}
    grok { match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:[@metadata][epoch]}" ]}
    date { match => [ "[@metadata][epoch]", "UNIX" ] }
    mutate { add_field => { "metric_type" => "gauge" }}
    mutate { add_field => { "metric_value" => "%{[@metadata][epoch]},%{response}" }}
    mutate { add_field => { "metric_name" => "logstash.uwsgi.response" }}
  }
}
```

Comment: The date{} filter does take a string and replace the @timestamp date field with the value.  Can you show what's in [@metadata][epoch] and what output you get?